# A functor of two categories, from category of ring, sending to its group of units, which is neither faithful nor full

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, category-theory, functors

For this question, there were originally a few questions in mind, but now just this one. I particularly want to get more feedback of PS part.

1. I refer to [this](http://math.mit.edu/%7Ephaine/files/Properties_of_Functors.pdf). But I really want to have a better understanding [***the part***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UE6cZ.png) highlighted, which explains why **the case is not faithful**, by using the example of *affine map and automorphism*.

PS: For category of ring, are there many morphisms K-algebra ring mapping itself, sending to the identity morphism of units group? Why there are many morphisms rather than one? Since automorphisms are all elements map to themselves?

definition of units ring: A ring with $1_{R}$ with multiplicative inverse elements. Why it is only an identity map?

What's the difference of mapping between the first category and the second one? I hope I explain my question clearly.

BTW: Downvoted does not help. Punishing rather than educating is meaningless.

Please let me know if you have any question about what I ask. Greatly appreciate your contribution here.

Comment: I've edited so that the image displays in the body of the post. I tried to keep the text sensible, but if it doesn't read right to you, you can edit it again.

Comment: What is your question? The paragraph explains how to construct nontrivial automorphisms of $k[x]$ which fix $k$ and hence which don't do anything to the group of units.

Comment: @Frances the author of the article considers a commutative field $K$ and exhibits a certain collection of ring endomorphisms of the polynomial ring $K[X]$ (endomorphisms which are actually the *automorphisms* of the $K$-algebra $K[X]$) which are all mapped to the identity endomorphism of the multiplicative group $K^{\times}$ under the ''group of units'' functor in question. This means that the functor is not faithful, as it fails to be injective between a certain pair of corresponding hom-sets in the given source and target categories.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ Can you provide the definition of endomorphisms of the polynomial ring K[X]? In mathematical language or way. Thank you

Comment: An endomorphism is a homomorphism whose domain is the same as its codomain.

Comment: To answer your "PS": yes, this is a good example of a functor which is not faithful. Why would it not be? Are there any other questions you'd like answered? If so, you need to ask them – linking to the thing you're confused about doesn't help us understand why you're confused.

Comment: Can the person who downvotes provides with your reasons? Thank you.